# how to allocate for two dimensional string array?

Tags: java

```
String[][] str=null;
str = new String[3];
```

*I have a array string as

```
String[][] str=null;
```

if i allocate the value of `str=new String[3]` it shows error.how to do it*

Comment: `str = new String[3][];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[][] str=null;
 str=new String[3][3];
```

Answer (score 1):

`String[][] str=null;` is a matrix not a vector. You have to initiate it as one instead. `String[rows][columns]`

Answer (score 1):

```
String[][] str=null;
str = new String[3];
```

You declare two dimension array but initialize like one dimension.

Code should be

```
String[][] str=null;
str=new String[1][1];
```

OR

```
String[][] str=null;
str=new String[2][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[][] str=null;
     str=new String[3][];
```

By default it will set the value as `null`